# How to reorder facets in tmap r?

Tags: r, facet, terra, tmap, r-stars

I want to reorder the facets of `tmap` raster plot. I am using the following code

```
library(tmap)
library(stars)
library(terra)

#Read some data
tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
x = rast(tif)

#Assign some fake names to the bands
names(x) <- c("RF_04.Apr.2022_LL", "RF_13.Dec.2021_LL", "RF_15.Feb.2022_LL", "RF_17.Dec.2020_LL", "RF_18.Nov.2021_LL", "RF_19.Feb.2021_LL")

#Plot it using tmap r package
tm_shape(x) +
  tm_raster(style="quantile")+
  tm_facets(nrow = 3) +
  tm_layout(panel.labels = names(x), 
            legend.outside=T, legend.outside.position = "right",
            legend.position= c("center", "center"),
            legend.text.size = 1,
            legend.format = list(digits = 2, text.separator = "-"))+
  tm_compass(position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"))+
  tm_scale_bar(breaks = c(0, 0.5), text.size = 1, position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"))
```

which returns me the following output
[image]

But I want to have the facets in the following sequence (i.e. in chronological order)

```
"RF_17.Dec.2020_LL", "RF_19.Feb.2021_LL", "RF_18.Nov.2021_LL",
"RF_13.Dec.2021_LL", "RF_15.Feb.2022_LL", "RF_04.Apr.2022_LL"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can modify your "facet variable" to ordered factor. Then it will plot accordantly to this order.

Comment: I suspect/assume that `tmap` is using `ggplot2` under the hood, in which case these questions are relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15116081/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5490638/3358272. In general, if a function is using `ggplot2`, then when asking about "order of" for facets, colors, axis labels, etc, the answer just about always includes `factor(.., levels=..)`.

Comment: Or you can reorder the raster layers prior to plotting it, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483664/r-change-order-of-layers-in-rasterstack

Comment: That's kind of strange, I would have assumed that it would be enough to change layer order through subsetting, i.e. `x[[c("RF_04.Apr.2022_LL", "RF_13.Dec.2021_LL")]]` vs  `x[[c("RF_13.Dec.2021_LL", "RF_04.Apr.2022_LL" )]]` (layer names can be parsed as dates for sorting),  but  `tmap`  changes facet rasters while keeping facet labels in their original order... go figure. Though this works as expected with `plot()`  and `ggplot2` + `tidyterra`. Are you only after tmap-based solutions?

Comment: @margusl Actually, `tmap` provides by default various style options like "cat", "fixed", "sd", "equal", "pretty", "quantile", "kmeans", "hclust", "bclust", "fisher", "jenks", "dpih", "headtails", and "log10_pretty" at the same time we can have different legends for individual facet plots which are not available in `ggplot2`.

Comment: In other words, you are after tmap? That's perfectly fine. Is there a chance that you are trying to fix a problem that's easier to avoid and the included example doesn't quite describe your actual use case? E.g. if you are reading layers from list of files , perhaps start by sorting that list?

Comment: @margusl I am very much open to other solutions which are easier. Yes, I am reading raster layers from list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of an issue with layer names and `tmap` (v3) facets when  changing SpatRaster layer order though subsetting. Here's a partial answer that might provide a workaround by first sorting filenames by encoded dates so layers in the resulting SpatRaster would be ordered chronologically, presumably fixing facet order:

```r
library(tidyverse)

file_list <- c("RF_04.Apr.2022_LL", "RF_13.Dec.2021_LL", "RF_15.Feb.2022_LL", "RF_17.Dec.2020_LL", "RF_18.Nov.2021_LL", "RF_19.Feb.2021_LL")

# extract dates, use file_list vector for names
date_list <- 
  file_list |> 
  stringr::str_extract("(?<=_).*(?=_)") |> 
  lubridate::dmy() |>
  setNames(file_list)
date_list
#> RF_04.Apr.2022_LL RF_13.Dec.2021_LL RF_15.Feb.2022_LL RF_17.Dec.2020_LL 
#>      "2022-04-04"      "2021-12-13"      "2022-02-15"      "2020-12-17" 
#> RF_18.Nov.2021_LL RF_19.Feb.2021_LL 
#>      "2021-11-18"      "2021-02-19"

# sort by dates, extract names
(file_list_sorted <- sort(date_list) |> names())
#> [1] "RF_17.Dec.2020_LL" "RF_19.Feb.2021_LL" "RF_18.Nov.2021_LL"
#> [4] "RF_13.Dec.2021_LL" "RF_15.Feb.2022_LL" "RF_04.Apr.2022_LL"

# import rasters
x = rast(file_list_sorted)

# alter names to only keep date values, part between _ & _
names(x) <- names(x) |> stringr::str_extract("(?<=_).*(?=_)")
names(x)
#> [1] "17.Dec.2020" "19.Feb.2021" "18.Nov.2021" "13.Dec.2021" "15.Feb.2022" "04.Apr.2022"


# continue with tmap
```

Comment: Actually, I want to remove `RF_` and `_LL` part and want to keep only the date part. You can make a edited part with the current solution with only dates as file names.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `tmap` only struggles with facet panel order, at least in my setup. So once you have loaded layers in correct order, renaming should not be an issue. And seems that another option would be using tmap v4, though it uses a somewhat different syntax.

Comment: I wanted to mean that in the actual plot I want the dates only as facet names. The `RF_` and `_LL` part is not required.

Comment: I understand, but I believe the key here is to have the file list sorted. So perhaps first test if it works for you fixes facet order, I can then update and alter layer names.